# File Monitoring and Upload via Google Chrome Extension

Tags: google-chrome, browser, google-chrome-extension, file-management, browser-extension

I am trying to build a Google Chrome Extension which does the following -

1) Gets activated when someone visits my site say http://example.com
2) When someone downloads a file from my site , http://example.com, it starts monitoring that file for changes. 
3) If the user edits and saves that file, it uploads the modified file back to the system.

My site is a niche document management system for a particular industry. Users dont want to downloads files, edit and then re-upload again. They want the files to be uploaded as soon as they save on their side. Its mostly for .docx, .xlsx files.

I tried to look at the Google chrome apis, but couldnt locate the appropriate ones. Any help would be useful.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you ever taken a look at [`chrome.downloads`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/downloads)? Especially [`chrome.downloads.onCreated`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/downloads#event-onCreated) and [`chrome.downloads.onChanged`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/downloads#event-onChanged)?

Comment: @HaibaraAi - I think I missed to look into chrome.downloads. Please add this as an answer and I will mark it as the answer. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your description, I believe [`chrome.downloads`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/downloads) is what you want.

> Use the `chrome.downloads` API to programmatically initiate, **monitor**, manipulate, and search for downloads.

To monitor, you could listen to [`chrome.downloads.onCreated`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/downloads#event-onCreated) and [`chrome.downloads.onChanged`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/downloads#event-onChanged)

Comment: chrome.downloads.onCreated doesn't fire once a user saves and opens the file in an application, like MS Word. Any suggestions?